# Partition integer into n parts with constraint

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to partition an integer n into m parts, with the constraint that each part is an element of set A?

I know its generation function is $(\sum_{a \in A}x^a)^m$, and the number of ways is the coefficient of $x^n$, but can anyone tell me how to find that coefficient? Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking for speedy algorithms?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is speedy algorithms. If it is an algorithm can find the coefficient with polynomial time complexity, yes, that is what I am asking for. Thanks.